# Arbitrary precision decimal arithmetic in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, browserify, amd

I'm looking to do precision decimal arithmetic in an Angular controller.

I have used the [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) module before in Node applications and would like to use it again in this instance.

It seems like I have a few options, I can use AMD / requirejs to require it (not exactly sure how though, not very familiar with requirejs), or I can link to its path.

My question though is, how can I include this javascript file to have it available to be used in my Angular controller?

If I include it is my base .html shell page, will it be available to my controller? Should I use browserify/requirejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use require.js. Including it in the base .html page normally will make the Big constructor available for all script modules (including controllers) defined after that.

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding normal library to Angular application it can be used globally. Framework isn't taking "responsibility" for it, because it isn't module, or directive. If it will be so, then you need to include it in your app constructor.